# AWS JS SDK S3 use custom configuration file

Tags: aws-sdk-js, s3cmd

I'm replacing `s3cmd` usage with AWS JS SDK.

In `s3cmd` command there is an option to set a custom config file: `s3cmd -c "/path/to/config"`. But I can't find how to use the same configuration file in "aws-sdk" (shared credentials file)?

My code looks like following:

```js
let cnf_file = path.join(__dirname, "../config");
process.env.AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE = cnf_file;
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
let s3 = new S3();
let params = {
//...
};
s3.putObject(params, (err, response) => {});
```

But I get errors:

message:
       'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',

message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',

Comment: what if you added `process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` at the top?

Comment: @mrblewog

finished with error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/vl/.aws/config'

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem was that `s3cmd` configuration file isn't compatible with `aws-sdk` because of different properties names for access key and secret key.

So I ended up with this line: `this.s3 = new S3({ accessKeyId, secretAccessKey });` which made it working.